# Calling list() twice on reversed() returns an empty list the second time

Tags: python

I don't understand the result of this code:

```
aa = 'hello, world'
bb = reversed(aa)
print(bb)
print(list(bb))
print(bb)
dd = list(bb)
print(dd)
print(''.join(dd))
```

The result:

```
<reversed object at 0x025C8C90>
['d', 'l', 'r', 'o', 'w', ' ', ',', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']
<reversed object at 0x025C8C90>
[]
```

Why is `dd` `[]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) creates an iterator, which is already spent when you're calling `list(bb)` for the second time.

```
aa = 'hello, world'
bb = reversed(aa)    # Creates an iterator, not a list
print(bb)            # Prints "<reversed object at 0x10c619b90>" (that's the iterator)
print(list(bb))      # Pops items from the iterator to create a list, then prints the list
print(bb)            # At this point the iterator is spent, and doesn't contain elements anymore
dd = list(bb)        # Empty iterator -> Empty list ([])
print(dd)
print(''.join(dd))
print('----------')
```

To fix that, just change `reversed(aa)` by `list(reversed(aa))`.