# Why does calling the list constructor twice result in an empty list?

Tags: python

I am learning python now and I met a question I don't know why

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = reversed(a)
>>> list(b)
[4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> list(b)
[]
```

Why the second time I called list(b) it returned an empty list

Comment: ask yourself: what is `b`? and what does `list()` really do?

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Comment: Or, not a duplicate of **that** question.

Comment: @erip Sure it is. It's exactly the same. Even down to the generator being `reversed`.

Comment: @erip: you have enough reputation to vote to reopen.

Comment: @MorganThrapp "What's the correct way to X" and "why does X happen" are definitely not the same.

Comment: Answering: b is not a list, is an iterator. For every time you ask for an item, you take it out.

Comment: " Attempting this with an iterator will just return the same exhausted iterator object used in the previous iteration pass, making it appear like an empty container." From the question.

Comment: Ah, indeed very meta. Question descriptions are now answers to questions. :)

Comment: Duplicate of [python list() return None](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18802417/2301450)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `b` is not the reversed list itself,  but a `listreverseiterator`.  So when you call `list()` the first time, it iterates over `b` and creates a new list from the items output from that iterator.  When you do it a second time, `b` is still the original iterator and has already gone through all the items, so it doesn't iterate over anything, resulting in an empty list